# Is this function macro safe?

Tags: c, macros

Can you tell me if anything and what can go wrong with this C "function macro"?

```
#define foo(P,I,X) do { (P)[I] = X; } while(0)
```

My goal is that `foo` behaves exactly like the following function `foofunc` for any POD data type `T` (i.e. `int`, `float*`, `struct my_struct { int a,b,c; }`):

```
static inline void foofunc(T* p, size_t i, T x) { p[i] = x; }
```

For example this is working correctly:

```
int i = 0;
float p;
foo(&p,i++,42.0f);
```

It can handle things like `&p` due to putting `P` in parentheses, it does increment `i` exactly once because `I` appears only once in the macro and it requires a semicolon at the end of the line due to `do {} while(0)`.

Are there other situations of which I am not aware of and in which the macro `foo` would not behave like the function `foofunc`?

In C++ one could define foofunc as a template and would not need the macro. But I look for a solution which works in plain C (C99).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to use a macro when `foofunc` will be inlined? There wouldn't be any performance benefit despite running risks with pointers.

Comment: foofunc only works for exactly on type T, thus one needs one definition per type. If I want foofunc for int, float* and my_struct I would need foofunc_int, foofunc_floatptr, foofunc_my_struct. The macro works with any type.

Comment: That's what templates are for. Just stick `template <typename T>` before your function definition and it'll work like you want it to.

Comment: You should write #define foo(P,I,X) do { *(P+I) = X; } while(0)

Comment: @parkovski: This question is about C, not C++. So no templates :(

Comment: @JatinKhurana: Why is *(P+I) better/different than P[I]?

Comment: Ok I see, and don't do `*(P+I)`. You can do that, but you need to group it as `*((P)+(I))` to avoid operator precedence issues in the macro. But it's the exact same as `P[I]` just less readable, so I would just leave it the way you've got it now.

Comment: @Danvil Sorry........ I have thought that indexing work only for int but it also work for size_t... P[I] is perfect......

Comment: If you're looking for ways in which this doesn't exactly match the function, here are two.  Firstly, something like `foo(p, i][j, 42)` will compile (assuming `p` is twice-indirected), as will other equally weird things.  Secondly, there is no function, so you cannot obtain a function-pointer for this.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth mentions a good point with weird parameters actually getting compiled. If you pedantically parenthesized then that should fix all the possible parameter issues (at least the ones I can imagine) (i.e. have your macro be `(P)[(I)] = (X)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your macro works for arbitrary `X` arguments hinges on the details of operator precedence. I recommend using parentheses even if they happen not to be necessary here.

```
#define foo(P,I,X) do { (P)[I] = (X); } while(0)
```

This is an instruction, not an expression, so it cannot be used everywhere `foofunc(P,I,X)` could be. Even if `foofunc` returns `void`, it can be used in comma expressions; `foo` can't. But you can easily define `foo` as an expression, with a cast to `void` if you don't want to risk using the result.

```
#define foo(P,I,X) ((void)((P)[I] = (X)))
```

With a macro instead of a function, all you lose is the error checking. For example, you can write `foo(3, ptr, 42)` instead of `foo(ptr, 3, 42)`. In an implementation where `size_t` is smaller than `ptrdiff_t`, using the function may truncate `I`, but the macro's behavior is more intuitive. The type of `X` may be different from the type that `P` points to: an automatic conversion will take place, so in effect it is the type of `P` that determines which typed `foofunc` is equivalent.

In the important respects, the macro is safe. With appropriate parentheses, if you pass syntactically reasonable arguments, you get a well-formed expansion. Since each parameter is used exactly once, all side effects will take place. The order of evaluation between the parameters is undefined either way.

Comment: Good point with the comma expressions! `int i; int*p=&i; if(foo(p,0,5), i==5) { /**/ }` would only work for `foofunc`, not for `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The `do { ... } while(0)` construct protects your result from any harm, your inputs `P` and `I` are protected by `()` and `[]`, respectively. What is not protected, is `X`. So the question is, whether protection is needed for `X`.

Looking at the operator precedence table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), we see that only two operators are listed as having lower precedence than `=` so that the assignment could steal their argument: the `throw` operator (this is C++ only) and the `,` operator.

Now, apart from being C++ only, the `throw` operator is uncritical because it does not have a left hand argument that could be stolen.
The `,` operator, on the other hand, would be a problem if `X` could contain it as a top level operator. But if you parse the statement

```
foo(array, index, x += y, y)
```

you see that the `,` operator would be interpreted to delimit a fourth argument, and

```
foo(array, index, (x += y, y))
```

already comes with the parentheses it requires.

---

To make a long story short:
Yes, your definition is safe.

However, your definition relies on the impossibility to pass `stuff, more_stuff` as one macro parameter without adding parentheses. I would prefer not to rely on such intricacies, and just write the obviously safe

```
#define foo(P, I, X) do { (P)[I] = (X); } while(0)
```